# I want logout a user after 1 hour once they go offline if they come online withn that 1 hour it should stop

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch

I tried saving my time in UserDefaults and adding 1 hour after once they go offline. I tried this too:

```
if isNetworkAvailable {
    print(isNetworkAvailable)
}
else {
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 10.0, execute: {
        self.logginout()
    })
}
```

I'm checking my Reachibility through Reachibility pod I have written a network manager like this:

```
import UIKit

class NetworkManager: NSObject {
    var reachability: Reachability!

    // Create a singleton instance
    static let sharedInstance: NetworkManager = { return NetworkManager() }()


    override init() {
        super.init()

        // Initialise reachability
        reachability = Reachability()!

        // Register an observer for the network status
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
            self,
            selector: #selector(networkStatusChanged(_:)),
            name: .reachabilityChanged,
            object: reachability
        )

        do {
            // Start the network status notifier
            try reachability.startNotifier()
        } catch {
            print("Unable to start notifier")
        }
    }

    @objc func networkStatusChanged(_ notification: Notification) {
        // Do something globally here!
    }

    static func stopNotifier() -> Void {
        do {
            // Stop the network status notifier
            try (NetworkManager.sharedInstance.reachability).startNotifier()
        } catch {
            print("Error stopping notifier")
        }
    }

    // Network is reachable
    static func isReachable(completed: @escaping (NetworkManager) -> Void) {
        if (NetworkManager.sharedInstance.reachability).connection != .none {
            completed(NetworkManager.sharedInstance)
        }
    }

    // Network is unreachable
    static func isUnreachable(completed: @escaping (NetworkManager) -> Void) {
        if (NetworkManager.sharedInstance.reachability).connection == .none {
            completed(NetworkManager.sharedInstance)
        }
    }

    // Network is reachable via WWAN/Cellular
    static func isReachableViaWWAN(completed: @escaping (NetworkManager) -> Void) {
        if (NetworkManager.sharedInstance.reachability).connection == .cellular {
            completed(NetworkManager.sharedInstance)
        }
    }

    // Network is reachable via WiFi
    static func isReachableViaWiFi(completed: @escaping (NetworkManager) -> Void) {
        if (NetworkManager.sharedInstance.reachability).connection == .wifi {
            completed(NetworkManager.sharedInstance)
        }
    }
}
```

And in delegate I'm checking it like this:

```
network.reachability.whenUnreachable = { unreach in
    isNetworkAvailable = false

    let banner = NotificationBanner(title: "Your offline", subtitle: "Please Connect to internet", style: .danger)
    banner.onSwipeUp = {
        banner.dismiss()
    }
    print(time)
    banner.show()
}
```

Is there a way to achieve this? I have written this block inside didLaunchWithOptions.

Comment: As per your question you should capture the time of logout and store it in defaults and, check the time on applicationDidBecomeActive or did application applicationWillEnterForeground (*whichever is best according to you )  ( "application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:" is not a good place if user doesn't kill the app.) whether the current time is more than an hour set status as not logged in. Keeping in mind that you have handled user has not change the time from settings and timezone issue is handled well.